# Build simple database search website with XML and XPath

Tags: javascript, xml, database, xslt, xpath

I need to do a XML project for university and I already build a XML file with a lot of cars and their specifications. My initial idea was to create a car search site with XSLT and XPath in the end. The user gives an input (for example min. 200 horsepower, convertible, 4 seats etc) and the input is transformed to a XPath expression which finds these cars. Is this even possible only with XML/XSLT/XPath? This is all happening client side and I am pretty sure I need atleast some JavaScript (do I even needd XSLT?). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: It's certainly possible to do the bulk of this using XSLT and XPath, and it will probably perform quite adequately if the XML is less than 1Mb in size. If you want to avoid writing any Javascript, you could do it with Saxon-JS [disclaimer: my company's product].

Answer (score 0):

If your source needs to be XML, and you understand the principles of Xslt/Xpath, it's excellent for transforming XML.
I.e. for building your search-form or showing the search-results.
For searching you could use Xslt as well, but probably an engine like [Solr](https://solr.apache.org/) would be a better fit.

I.e. if you really need to use xslt for searching and assuming you define only 2 parameters in your xslt:
A xslt 1.0 could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="searchName" />
<xsl:param name="searchPhrase"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()=$searchName and contains(text(),$searchPhrase)" >
            <!-- Do something with the result that matches both the element-name and the search-phrase of only the current textnodes-->
    
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(text(),$searchPhrase)" >
            <!-- Do something with the result that matches only the search-phrase-->
    
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. How is the searching possible with Xslt? I have no idea how to convert the user input into a xpath expression